# error query in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

ALL stored procedure

```
USE [amozeshgah]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[selectmanageregistercourse] ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[selectmanageregistercourse]
@iddore int,
@stateregister int,
@userid nvarchar(350)
AS
declare @str nvarchar(900)
BEGIN
SET @str= 'SELECT tblUserRegisterDore.id, tblUserRegisterDore.idcourse, tblUserRegisterDore.iddore, tblUserRegisterDore.userid, tblUserRegisterDore.coderegister, tblUserRegisterDore.fish, tblUserRegisterDore.date, tblUserRegisterDore.statefish, tblUserRegisterDore.stateregister, tbluser.name, tbldore.name AS namesubcourse, tblmozedore.name AS namecourse, tbluser.family FROM tblUserRegisterDore INNER JOIN tblmozedore ON tblUserRegisterDore.idcourse = tblmozedore.id INNER JOIN tbldore ON tblUserRegisterDore.iddore = tbldore.id AND tblmozedore.id = tbldore.idmozedore INNER JOIN tbluser ON tblUserRegisterDore.userid = tbluser.userid where  iddore='+convert(nvarchar(100),@iddore)
 if (@stateregister<>-1)
begin
set @str +=' and stateregister='+ convert(varchar(100),@stateregister)
end 
if (@userid <>'-1')
begin
set @str +=' and tblUserRegisterDore.userid='+ @userid
end
EXEC sp_executesql @str 
END
```

when run query  vlaue @userid in where  error 'Invalid column name value @user id'

parameters that are passed

```
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[selectmanageregistercourse]
        @iddore = 3,
        @stateregister = 1,
        @userid = N'fdfsdf'
```

error
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'fdfsdf'.

why?

Comment: Would you show what is passed in to the procedure?  I think the problem is in the input values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues here and it seems the file you are showing is not the one you are using on the server.

Here is how to create SP and not use dynamic SQL -- it will be much faster and easier to use:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[selectmanageregistercourse]
@iddore int,
@stateregister int,
@fish nvarchar(350)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT tblUserRegisterDore.id, tblUserRegisterDore.idcourse, tblUserRegisterDore.iddore, 
           tblUserRegisterDore.userid, tblUserRegisterDore.coderegister, tblUserRegisterDore.fish, tblUserRegisterDore.date, 
           tblUserRegisterDore.statefish, tblUserRegisterDore.stateregister, tbluser.name, tbldore.name AS namesubcourse, 
           tblmozedore.name AS namecourse, tbluser.family 
    FROM tblUserRegisterDore 
    INNER JOIN tblmozedore ON tblUserRegisterDore.idcourse = tblmozedore.id 
    INNER JOIN tbldore ON tblUserRegisterDore.iddore = tbldore.id AND tblmozedore.id = tbldore.idmozedore 
    INNER JOIN tbluser ON tblUserRegisterDore.userid = tbluser.userid 
    WHERE iddore=@iddore
     AND ((@stateregister =-1) OR (stateregister=@stateregister))
     AND ((@fish ='-1') OR (tblUserRegisterDore.fish=@fish))
END
```

---

**Prior comment no longer applies if you use above**

However, here is one issue.  You have a `varchar` and you are not using quotes around it in the dynamic sql you are creating.

```
set @str +=' and tblUserRegisterDore.fish='+ @fish
```

should be

```
set @str +=' and tblUserRegisterDore.fish='''+ @fish + ''''
```

Comment: Nice catch about the quotes. I'd also add that it might be safer to prepend string constants with `N` in this case, like in `set @str +=N' and tblUserRegisterDore.fish='''+ …`